# AWS EC2 instance not showing Rails app production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, dev-to-production

Quick newbie question. I have a simple Rails app that I want to put into production. I would like to deploy it in a AWS EC2 server. The app works perfectly fine locally on the port 3000.

I tried running the container and although it says that is listening on the port 3000, when I try to go to: 13.241.213.464:3000 on the browser it keeps loading without showing anything.

I read around the internet that you need to change your CMD on the Dockerfile to make it run so I changed it from this:

```
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

to this:

```
CMD ["bundle",  "exec", "rails", "server", "-e", "production"]
```

So now my `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
# Start from the official ruby image, then update and install JS & DB
FROM ruby:2.6.6
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs postgresql-client

# Create a directory for the application and use it
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp

# Gemfile and lock file need to be present, they'll be overwritten immediately
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock

# Install gem dependencies
RUN gem install bundler:2.2.32
RUN bundle install
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y yarn  && apt-get install -y npm
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn add bootstrap jquery popper.js
COPY . /myapp

# This script runs every time the container is created, necessary for rails
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

# Start rails
CMD ["bundle",  "exec", "rails", "server", "-e", "production"]
```

My `docker-compose.yml` is:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_HOST: db
```

And the `entrypoint.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Rails-specific issue, deletes a pre-existing server, if it exists

set -e

rm -f /myapp/tmp/pids/server.pid

exec "$@"
```

To run the container for production I run the `docker-compose.override.yml` :

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    image: "dockerhub_user/repo:${WEB_TAG:-latest}"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_HOST: db
```

I run it like this: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.override.yml up`

It still keeps loading without showing anything.

I also read about some projects that have `nginx` but I am not sure if it is needed or not to make it work. I kind of understood the `nginx` help to proxy the requests between users and the Rails app, is it correct?
Then, do I need `nginx` to make it work in production?

Any kind of enlightment is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Your image sets an `ENTRYPOINT`, which is passed the `bundle exec rails ...` command as arguments; what's in that script?

Comment: (Probably the `rm -f server.pid` should be in the entrypoint script, and when the script runs the image's `CMD`, it should `exec bundle exec "$@"`.  Then you wouldn't need to modify the `CMD` to run things under Bundler.  You should not normally need a Compose `command:` override.  For production and any path leading up to it, you also do not want a `volumes:` block overriding the image's code.)

Comment: Thank you for the message @DavidMaze . I updated the question with the `entrypoint.sh` and also the `docker-compose.override.yml` which is the one that I tried to run for production like this `docker-compose -f docker-compose.override.yml up`

Comment: You dropped the `rails server -b 0.0.0.0` option, and it's important.  You also might consider using Unicorn or another server package instead of the Rails development server.  The Nginx proxy isn't essential.

Comment: I removed it because the deployment wasn´t working and I read the command `"bundle",  "exec", "rails", "server", "-e", "production"` would do the trick. I guess that I need some kind of tool to deploy Rails to production in the end right? @DavidMaze

Comment: Possibly setting `ENV RAILS_ENV=production`, and leaving the `CMD` unchanged, will have the effect you want?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DavidMaze . I tried but with no luck. I changed the CMD to `CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]` , set the `RAILS_ENV=production` in the `.env` file of the project. Ran it like `docker-compose -f docker-compose.override.yml up`. It is listening on port 3000. If I do `docker ps` this is what I get:
`0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp   jenkins_project_web_1` for the web and `5432/tcp                                    jenkins_project_db_1`  for the db. But when I try to go onto the AWS EC2 server public IP:3000 it keeps loading

Comment: Does this exact setup work on your local system?  (Are AWS security groups blocking the inbound connection?)

Comment: Sorry for the wait. I was trying several stuff on the local system and now it is works locally for production. But it is still failing on AWS EC2 with the same setup. I will check if AWS is blocking it.. Thanks @DavidMaze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up building `nginx` but even then it was not working. Then I realized it might be the `Inbound and outbound rules` in the Security of the AWS EC2 instance.

So, right now, my app is listening on port 80 (because of nginx). What I did was to create a couple of `Inbound rules`:

```
80  TCP 0.0.0.0/0
80  TCP ::/0
```

With this, it is now showing the app once I go into the `public ip of the instance:80`.

Hope this helps someone in need in the future